# Showing a CKRecord on the map using its "Location"

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cloudkit

I am trying to have each CKRecord I have in a custom zone show up on my map individually as an annotation. I use the annotation title and subtitle as other fields in the CKRecord but for the annotation.cordinate, I'm having a rough time connecting that to the CKRecord's "location" field.

```
func fetchTruck() {
    let truePredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let eventQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: truePredicate)
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: eventQuery)

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record : CKRecord!) in
        self.truck.append(record)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = record["username"] as? String
        annotation.subtitle = record["hours"] as? String
        **if let location = record["location"] as? CLLocation {
annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate}** Answer 

        print("recordFetchedBlock: \(record)")

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
        print("queryCompletionBlock: \(self.truck)")
    }

    database.add(queryOperation)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchTruck()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CKRecord` will have a location field. That will be a value of type `CLLocation`.

The `coordinate` property of `MKPointAnnotation` is of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

`CLLocation` has a `coordinate` property which is also of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

```
if let location = record["location"] as? CLLocation {
    annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
}
```

Comment: Thank rmaddy for the answer! I inserted the answer and ran my app and it doesn't crash anymore haha. It is still not showing what I want but I might have made a mistake inserting your answer. I edited my question to what it currently looks like.....

Comment: I rolled back your edit since your edit made my answer obsolete. Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on that new `if` statement. Verify it does what you expect. And see my updated answer. I had a typo.

Comment: You're a genius rmaddy! Didn't even have to use breakpoints just copied and paste the answer. Thanks again